# trying to use the same jquery-accordion script to work in 2 different ways

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

Im using jQuery accordion and I have a doubt.
I have a page that I want that my first div of my accordion starts open, so Im using `active: 0` in my script.

But I have other page in same project that I dont want any div open, I just want to open if the user clicks to open, and I know that we do that with `active:true.`

Is possible in same project have only 1 script like I have below, and have this two different conditions depending on the page like I said?

```
$(function (){

        $('.accordion').accordion({
            //active: true 
            active: 0,
            collapsible: true 
        });
    });
```

Comment: You should not call $().accordion() on the same element multiple times. If you call it once on div1 and set it to active: 0 and then call it on div2 and set active:true, that should be fine. Does this answer your question?

Comment: Thanks for youar answer. If I understand you good, you are saying to use two scripts? One script for each accordion div?

Comment: Id doesnt matter if they are called within the same javascript file. What matters is if you are calling accordion() on the same html element.

Comment: Yes, I have a page1.php file and I have a div id="accordion" and then I have other div id="accordion" in a page2.php file that is in the same folder of my project folder.